# How to remove item from menu programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I've created bottom bar navigation with menu. I want to remove menu items by checking some conditions, so i want it remove using java code. I have tried it using `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, but somehow it did not work. I don't know what am i doing wrong, a little help would be appreciated.

```
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.member_activities);        
            BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomViewBar);
            BottomNavigationViewHelper.disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
            menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
            MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(0);
            menuItem.setChecked(true);
}
  @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            this.menu = menu;
            menu.removeItem(R.id.district_tab);
            return true;
        }
```

bottom_navigation_menu.xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/member_tab"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_outline"
    android:title="Member"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/club_tab"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_outline"
    android:title="Club"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/district_tab"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_outline"
    android:title="District"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/ag_tab"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_outline"
    android:title="AG"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/dg_tab"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_person_outline"
    android:title="DG"/>
```

Comment: I suggest you don't actually do that. Just hide them instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`onCreateOptionsMenu` its for the menu in the toolbar.

For the menu in your BottomNavigationView you need to use `bottomNavigationView.getMenu().removeItem(R.id.district_tab);` in `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 3):

try this Please:

```
bottomNavigationView.getMenu().removeItem(R.id.district_tab);
```

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use bottom navigation view's reference to remove item:

```
bottomNavigationView.getMenu().removeItem(R.id.district_tab);
```